# Java: Key for algorithm RSA not suitable for symmetric enryption.

Tags: java, aes, rsa, cbc-mode

I'm trying to encrypt a file with AES/CBC, the key must be random AND encrypted with RSA.
I'm getting "Key for algorithm RSA not suitable for symmetric enryption."...what seems to be the problem?

this is part of my code:

```
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    byte[] input = "Encryption Test".getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC"); // init Cipher to use AES/CBC
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); // IV is random 
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC"); // Key will be generated with RSA

    generator.initialize(512, random);
    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    Key pubKey = pair.getPublic();
    //Key privKey = pair.getPrivate();

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, random);
```

Comment: if you are getting an error then post the stack trace, otherwise you are wasting our time.

Comment: cipher is an aes cipher, but pubkey is an rsa public key.

Comment: How are you running this code? What do you do that gives the purported error?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a RSA key with a AES cipher...

use this instead:

```
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
 keyGen.init(256);
 Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
```

here you can find a [code example.](http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/Security/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

Comment: Of course, you will then need to extract the bytes of your AES key and encrypt them with your RSA public key.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on wanting to use a key-exchange cipher for key-exchange! Sometimes I wonder why so many people on the internet try to turn RSA into a stream cipher.

The sample code below shows you how to do this.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Generate an RSA key pair and save it to the file
     */
    public static KeyPair genKeys(File keyFile) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Generating RSA keys");

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubSpec = factory.getKeySpec(kp.getPublic(),
                X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = factory.getKeySpec(kp.getPrivate(),
                PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.class);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keyFile);
        DataOutputStream dat = new DataOutputStream(out);

        byte[] enc = pubSpec.getEncoded();
        dat.writeInt(enc.length);
        dat.write(enc);

        enc = privSpec.getEncoded();
        dat.writeInt(enc.length);
        dat.write(enc);
        dat.flush();
        dat.close();

        System.out.println("RSA keys saved to " + keyFile.getPath());

        return kp;
    }


    /**
     * Load an RSA key pair from the file
     */
    public static KeyPair loadKeys(File keyFile) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading RSA keys");

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
        DataInputStream dat = new DataInputStream(in);

        int len = dat.readInt();
        byte[] enc = new byte[len];
        dat.readFully(enc);
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(enc);

        len = dat.readInt();
        enc = new byte[len];
        dat.readFully(enc);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(enc);

        dat.close();

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
        PrivateKey priv = factory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

        System.out.println("RSA keys loaded from " + keyFile.getPath());
        return new KeyPair(pub, priv);
    }


    /**
     * Decrypt a file
     */
    public static void decrypt(KeyPair kp, File inFile, File outFile) throws Exception {
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        DataInputStream dat = new DataInputStream(in);

        // read RSA encrypted AES key
        int len = dat.readInt();
        byte[] buf = new byte[len];
        dat.readFully(buf);
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kp.getPrivate());

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(rsa.doFinal(buf), "AES");

        // read the AES IV
        len = dat.readInt();
        buf = new byte[len];
        dat.readFully(buf);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(buf);

        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        // process the rest of the file to get the original back
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        buf = new byte[1000];
        int r = -1;
        while( (r = dat.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
            byte[] sec = aes.update(buf, 0, r);
            if (sec != null) out.write(sec);
        }
        out.write(aes.doFinal());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }


    public static void encrypt(KeyPair kp, File inFile, File outFile) throws Exception {
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");

        // create new AES key
        KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        gen.init(256);
        SecretKey key = gen.generateKey();

        // RSA encrypt AES key
        byte[] keyEnc = key.getEncoded();
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kp.getPublic());
        byte[] keySec = rsa.doFinal(keyEnc);

        // Create AES cipher
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] iv = aes.getIV();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        DataOutputStream dat = new DataOutputStream(out);

        // save encrypted AES key and IV
        dat.writeInt(keySec.length);
        dat.write(keySec);
        dat.writeInt(iv.length);
        dat.write(iv);

        // save the encrypted file
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1000];
        int r = -1;
        while( (r = in.read(buf)) != -1 ) {
            byte[] sec = aes.update(buf, 0, r);
            if (sec != null) dat.write(sec);
        }
        dat.write(aes.doFinal());
        dat.flush();
        dat.close();
        in.close();
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Test (encrpyt|decrypt) keyFile inFile outFile");
            return;
        }
        KeyPair kp;
        File keyFile = new File(args[0]);
        if (!keyFile.canRead()) {
            kp = genKeys(keyFile);
        } else {
            kp = loadKeys(keyFile);
        }

        boolean isEnc = args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt");
        boolean isDec = args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt");
        File inFile = new File(args[2]);
        File outFile = new File(args[3]);
        if (!(isEnc || isDec) || !inFile.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Test (encrpyt|decrypt) keyFile inFile outFile");
            return;
        }

        if (isEnc) {
            encrypt(kp, inFile, outFile);
        } else {
            decrypt(kp, inFile, outFile);
        }
    }
}
```